# Can I transform my sub-columns into columns? R

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a dataframe which some columns contain lists (or subcolumns), I would like to transform these lists into columns in my dataframe.

```
head = head(components, 10)

head
```

[image]

This is what is shown in the R environment

[image]

I put part of the dataframe in a drive :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14yj6c76sLbcNMbrNYWYS0C1Siq_3EB6b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Share your data as `dput(components)`. I think you need unnest - https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a column for each element of the list, you can use [unnest_wider](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html?q=unnest_wider) for each list.

```
unnest_wider(head, col = quantitativ)
```